# MySQL - Using dynamicsql on Update

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

I'm working with MySQL 5.6 and trying to a simple procedure seen below.

```
drop procedure if exists procsBook;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE procsBook()

main:begin

DECLARE abc VARCHAR(256);

DECLARE def VARCHAR(256);

DECLARE field_name2 VARCHAR(256);

DECLARE field_names VARCHAR(256);

DECLARE bkid BIGINT(20);

SET abc:= NULL;

SET def:= NULL;

SET field_name2:= NULL;

SET field_names:= NULL;

SET bkid:= 0;

select a.field_name,b.column_name into abc,def from  table1 a join table2 b where a.field_label=b.field_label and b.table_name='Table13' and b.section_name='English' group by a.field_name limit 1;

IF(abc is not null)
then

IF (SUBSTRING(abc,7,1)=1)

THEN

SELECT book1,bookId INTO field_names,bkid FROM shelf1 WHERE rowstate=0;

SET @vSelectQury = CONCAT('update shelf2 set def = ' , field_names, ' where book_id = ', bkid);
PREPARE vDynamicSSql FROM @vSelectQury;

EXECUTE vDynamicSSql;

DEALLOCATE PREPARE vDynamicSSql;

END IF;

END IF;

END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Call:

```
call procsBook();
```

This is throwing the following error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where book_id = 22' at line 1
```

Any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to add quotes around field_names.

> SET @vSelectQury = CONCAT('update shelf2 set ', def, ' = \'' , field_names,
>   '\' where book_id = ', bkid); PREPARE vDynamicSSql FROM @vSelectQury;

(or if your setup is different you may need to change the escaping for ' character)

**Updated** you should not directly use def, but use the value of def in this case.

Comment: Part of it is solved. But 'def' is a value taken from table 'table2', which is in turn used as column of table 'shelf2'. So the above query would need some modification.